# Circular dependency detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I've installed the gem rails_admin, I've added to Gemfile:

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine, :at => '/admin'
```

But when I try to visit http://lvh.me:3000/admin I get this error:

```
RuntimeError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ActiveRecord::AddResetPkSequenceToBase
```

Any idea?

Comment: did you figure this out? im having the same problem.

Comment: No, didn't hear from anyone, I turned to rails active admin gem, it worked fine..